# SonarQube Eclipse plugin throws error on local analysis

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

We are running SonarQube 3.7. I'm using the SonarQube plugin for Eclipse, version 3.2.0.20130627-1142, on Eclipse 3.7.2. I have associated my projects with the SonarQube projects and am able to view issues from the server side great.
However, if I switch to Local analysis, I get the following error, after CheckStyle, PMD, etc have run:

```
15:16:23.217 INFO  - Execute decorators...
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:79)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:63)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:57)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to decorate 'CLASSPATH.REDACTED.ClockEventHelperIT'
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:71)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:64)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:64)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.execute(DecoratorsExecutor.java:56)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:118)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:88)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:73)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:186)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:181)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:174)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:88)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:73)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:82)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:88)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:73)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:156)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doAfterStart(BootstrapContainer.java:144)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:88)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:73)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$HttpException: Fail to download [http://cm-sonar/api/sources?resource=REDACTED:shared-core:REDACTED.ClockEventHelperIT&amp;format=txt]. Response code: 500
    at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:266)
    at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(HttpDownloader.java:230)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:88)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.request(ServerClient.java:82)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.LastSnapshots.loadSourceFromWs(LastSnapshots.java:62)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.LastSnapshots.getSource(LastSnapshots.java:52)
    at org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTracking.mapIssues(IssueTracking.java:82)
    at org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTracking.track(IssueTracking.java:59)
    at org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTrackingDecorator.doDecorate(IssueTrackingDecorator.java:107)
    at org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTrackingDecorator.decorate(IssueTrackingDecorator.java:91)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:80)
    ... 36 more
```

Everything runs fine on the server. Any ideas?

Comment: what happens when you try to reach 'http://cm-sonar/api/sources?resource=REDACTED:shared-core:REDACTED.ClockEventHelperIT&amp;format=txt' from your browser ?

Comment: Having the same issue with the same version of server and Eclipse plugin.  If I click on the link I get an error page from Sonar that says there was a problem and the page can't be displayed.  This issue happens for some and not for others, very strange.

Comment: @FreddyMallet-SonarSource if I go to the link from the error in my browser, it says: "undefined method `source' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: The offending file seems to have key `CLASSPATH.REDACTED.ClockEventHelperIT`. But the WS ask for effective key `REDACTED:shared-core:REDACTED.ClockEventHelperIT`. `REDACTED:shared-core` must be the project key so its fine. But then the second part of the key is `REDACTED.ClockEventHelperIT`. Can you just give/confirm the following information: project key (`REDACTED:shared-core`), source folder path relative to root project (`src/main/java` ?), path of offending file (`src/main/java/CLASSPATH/REDACTED/ClockEventHelperIT.java` ?), and package of offending file (`CLASSPATH.REDACTED` ?)

Comment: @JulienHENRY Sorry, in my redaction of the actual classpaths, in one place I just wrote "REDACTED" and in the other place I wrote "CLASSPATH.REDACTED". These are actually the same.

Comment: @JulienHENRY, here are the answers to each of your questions.

I'm using fake classpaths here but the patterns match the real ones. 

Project key: `com.company.project.toolsuite:shared-core`.

We have multiple source folders in the project -- this particular one is `runtime-tests`.

Java file path relative to project root: `runtime-tests/com/company/project/shared/ClockEventHelperIT.java`.

Package name is: `com.company.project.shared`.

Please let me know what else I can provide to help.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered a "Unable to execute Sonar... Fail to download... Response code: 500" with my installation (Sonar v3.7.2, Eclipse plugin v3.2 and Eclipse 4.3) when running a local analysis.

I noticed one of my classes in my stacktrace Caused by line (where yours shows "ClockEventHelperIT"). The class doesn't exist in my server side repository (it's new) and is also located in the default Java package. It was a throwaway class so I decided to remove it and re-run the analysis. That solved it for me.

Comment: In my case this class mentioned is already in the server's analysis. In fact I haven't even changed that file.

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing the same problem off and on with our projects.  The "fix" that we have found is to make sure that the case that the username is in the sonar plugin matchese the case that they would log into the sonar server with.  For now, this has fixed this particular issue, though I'm not sure if it actually fixes a problem.

When debugging we found no errors in the sonar logs, this is a very strange issue.

For your information we are running local analysis in Eclipse on Windows 7, and our Sonar Server is running on Red Hat Enterprise 6.2

Comment: We aren't normally using any credentials to log in to the SonarQube server. In our organization, only project leads and the Configuration Management team have accounts on SonarQube. So I'm not sure if this would even apply to me (what login would I put in the plugin configuration, if I don't use one normally to look at SonarQube?)

Comment: At the sonar level project permissions configuration you can configure the 'anonymous' group to be able to run local scans or dry runs.  That should be what you need.

Comment: However, if it works sometimes and not others regardless of configuring the authentication, it sounds like there's probably a bug here.

Comment: It is due to authentication every time for our team.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and for us it was because the class identified in the stack trace was in a non-standard folder (Maven standard). (i.e. outside the `src/main/java, src/test/java, src/main/resources, src/test/resources`).

I refactored these classes into the standard Maven folders and this problem was fixed.